# No Code Signature Found after Cocoapod Install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, code-signing

I recently installed cocoapods on two of my xCode projects and they both won't install on my physical iPhone.

The two projects are a weather app and a bitcoin tracker app, both using alamofire and swiftyjson.

Running on the simulator they are fine. **These are the things I've tried**:

1. Cleaning the projects
2. Closed xCode and reopened
3. Restarted iPhone
4. Tested a blank project if it will install onto my physical phone, worked fine
5. Tried to tick auto manage signing on Pods project in the file inspector on the left hand side of xCode

Please send help!

EDIT: Link to video of what happens when I run it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMe3Q0pd1Eo

Comment: Look at the [Cocoapods answer for this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42861383/981049) and give those approaches a try.

Comment: What kind of error are you experiencing? You say they won't install on your iPhone - is there an error message during installation or execution?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMe3Q0pd1Eo Here's a video that shows the error, there are no error logs but that prompt shows up and nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Go to `project > build setting and set signing > code signing identity to iOS developer` or Remove all data in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

Follow this link:

[App Installation Failed Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371044/ios-app-testing-app-installation-failed-no-code-signature-found)

Comment: Do the second one

Comment: I gave it a go, unfortunately it still does not work.. The same error pops up

Comment: Follow the link and you will see an answer with most upvotes. Follow each of them and do let me know if that solution works.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how to do the top question, unfortunately I'm only a beginner. This one "i'm my case problem was on unsigned frameworks: build phases > copy files > code sign on copy (set check boxes)"

Where do I check build phases in? As well as do I hit the + and copy files? When I do that I can't click on code sign on copy

Comment: I had to do both steps in order for this to resolve the error.  I'm using xCode version 10.1 (10B61) and my target build device is an iPhone X.